# I want to create a set of data arrays within a loop and name it according to a variable list

Tags: arrays, r, loops, time-series

I want to import several time-series variables for a list of countries via an API function. I want to store the data in a separate array for each country. The name of the data array should be the 3 letter country code. For one country my code looks like this:

```
data = Quandl(c(var1,var2,var3), collapse="annual")
```

I want to loop through a list of countries that also contains the identifiers to download var1-3 from Quandl.com. My problem is that I cannot figure out a way to rename the data array (data) for each country with the respective country code (e.g. USA). In the end I want to have a separate data arrays for each country on my list in the workspace (POL, DEU, USA, CHN ...).

Basically, I'm looking for a functional way to do this:

```
list[i,1] = data
```

unfortunately, this isn't working but why isn't there a simple way to rename a data array within a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a list of of the data using `lapply` and then rename each element of the list with the country codes.

```
countries<-c("a","b","c")
dat<-lapply(countries,function(x) rnorm(4))
names(dat)<-countries
> dat[["a"]]
[1] -0.5157099 -1.0372721  0.9696698 -0.9280852
```

You won't have a variable named POL or USA, but you'll have a list from which you can extract the relevant dataframe. I think this might be a cleaner solution than creating variables for each country.

You can probably do away with your loop by looking into one of the apply functions (`apply`, `mapply`, `sapply`, `lapply` etc). Consider the following:
 The outer lapply performs the function of the overall higher country-level "loop", while the inner mapply performs a given set of operations for various arguments for that single country

```
countries<-c("a","b","c")
arg1<-1:3
arg2<-10*1:3
dat<-mapply(data.frame(c1=x,c2=rnorm(1)*vars),vars,x,SIMPLIFY=F))
names(dat)<-countries


dat<-lapply(countries, function(x)
          do.call(rbind,
                  mapply(function(x,y,z) data.frame(country=x,c1=rnorm(2)*y,c2=rnorm(2)*z),
                        x=x,y=arg1,z=arg2,SIMPLIFY=F)))
```

If you still want to stick with your for loop then create a list and add into it and rename as done above

```
result<-list()
 for(i in 1:50)   result[[i]]<-YOURFUNCTIONHERE
names(result)<-countryNames
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how this would tie into my for loop structure. Maybe I should have explained more clearly, that each var1-3 has a different ID code and the differences go beyond the country identifier. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I see. I will edit my response. What I am getting at, is that you don't really need a for loop. For the most part, you should try to avoid for loops in languages that support vector operations.

Comment: I know it would be more elegant this way but I'm really not sure this would work with the API function that I need to call. I've rewritten my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388404/r-how-to-rename-a-dataframe-within-a-for-loop

Comment: I hope my additional post helps to clarify the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I sticked with the loop. Thanks for introducing me to the functionality of lists.