# R: how to rename a dataframe within a for loop?

Tags: r, api, loops, for-loop, dataframe

I have to run an API download function for several countries separately. My variables are strings that I read in from an Excel-list. Each observation is identified by a three letter country identifier(`codes[i,1]`). Ideally, I would want to do this:

```
codes = read.xls("data.xlsx")

for(i in 1:50) {
codes[i,1] = Quandl(c(toString(codes[i,2]),toString(codes[i,3]),toString(codes[i,4])), collapse="annual")
}
```

obviously, `codes[i,1] = ...` doesn't work. Is there a simple solution to this problem. Performance isn't a major concern. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
codes = read.xls("data.xlsx")

for(i in 1:50) {
assign(codes[i,1], Quandl(c(toString(codes[i,2]),toString(codes[i,3]),toString(codes[i,4])), collapse="annual"))
}
```

Try that.